# Groovy + Vaadin + IntelliJ IDEA: Works fine until I reference a custom jar

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, vaadin

I have successfully created an IntelliJ IDEA Groovy + Vaadin project that works great *until I try to reference another jar that I wrote.*  I've added the jar to `lib/` and `web/WEB-INF/lib/` and included both in my Modules/Dependencies:

[image: Modules/Dependencies window]

I even promoted the `lib/` instance to be a "global library" so I could add it to my Artifacts like so:

[image: Artifacts]

IntelliJ builds fine and launches Tomcat, but when I try to view my app in a browser, I receive HTTP Status 500 with the error:

`The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`

...and my Tomcat logs state:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.qview.client.QueueViewApplication`

Is there any way that I can gain insight into why QueueViewApplication failed to load?  Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue dealt with how I was building my custom jar.

In IntelliJ IDEA, under **Project Structure » Artifacts » [+] » Jar » From modules with dependencies...** I was selecting ***extract to the target jar***

This bundles QueueUpdater.jar's dependency jars into one massive QueueUpdater.jar for convenient import.

But, when I changed my selection to **copy to the output directory and link via manifest**, I was able to add the individual jars to `web/WEB-INF/lib/` and run the Vaadin application without error.